# uploading photos with sir trevor editor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sirtrevor

I have just discovered Sir Trevor editor, I am trying to integrate it into my rails app, but the image uploading dosent seem to work. Does any one know how to do that with carrierwave or paperclip

Answer (score 1):

By default, [Sir Trevor](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js) will attempt to post any images uploads to /attachments. You can read about this [behaviour in the docs](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/docs.html#3-2), but in essence the following parameters will be POSTed to /attachments;

```
attachment[name] – the files name
attachment[file] – the file
attachment[uid] – a unique identifier for this file
```

You can use this to either upload the file directly, or create a model to store each attachment and mount Carrierwave or Paperclip to handle the file upload.

To upload the file directly, your controller would look something like this..

```
class AttachmentsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    uploader = SirTrevorImageUploader.new
    if uploader.store! params[:attachment][:file]
      render json: { file: { url: uploader.url } }, status: 200
    else
      render :json => uploader.errors, status: 422
    end 
  end
end
```

Note the JSON hash that is returned on success - the Image block requires this structure to work.

You can change the URL Sir Trevor posts the image to with the following config;

```
SirTrevor.setDefaults({
  uploadUrl: "/images"
});
```